# How to compile latest FFmpeg Library for Android?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

Struggling to put together a working and generally best practice build of current FFmpeg. There seems to be no up-to-date documents or tutorials. What does exist is full of outdated links or build-scripts that do not work.

Comment: It would help if you posted some information about what you have tried, what errors you are seeing, and what step specifically is confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found!

Please check following links:

- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android
- https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
- http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android/
- http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

Comment: Answers that are just links are discourages. It is recommended to provide some context.

Answer (score 6):

#### Build the standalone NDK Toolchain

Download the latest NDK and run `make_standalone_toolchain.py`

#### Configure FFmpeg

```
./configure \
--cross-prefix=arm-linux-androideabi- \
--sysroot="${ANDROID_STANDALONE_NDK}/sysroot" \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=cortex-a8 \
--enable-cross-compile \
--enable-pic \
--enable-shared \
--extra-cflags="-fpic"
```

Then of course

```
make -j4
```

You probably don't want to compile a lot of the components, so you'll need to see what to enable/disable in `./configure --help`

Comment: I have android stdio installed, should i follow the same.

Comment: @AbdulMuheet yes. Android Studio isn't really applicable in this case since FFMPEG has its own build system. You'll want to compile the library and then bring it into your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i will try.

Comment: @AbdulMuheet I have to deal with cross-compiled external libraries all the time and they're all a pain and usually involve Autoconf and Make. Just compile a static library for your desired architecture targets and link it and include the headers.

Comment: What does `make_stanalone_toolchain.py` do? Should i run it right where it is located or i should copyt it to my projects directoty ?

Comment: Good question! It is in the NDK and it "creates a toolchain installation for a given Android target." A toolchain more suitable for use in cross-compiling software using autotools

Answer (score 0):

After reading so many post, I've managed to find the way to generate the ffmpeg library for an android

Download below mentioned code and having it as **ffmpeg.sh** and execute the same in your ffmpeg source root folder and do `make`

```
#!/bin/bash
BASEDIR=$(pwd)
TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX=/opt/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CFLAGS='-U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all'
LDFLAGS='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie'

./configure \
--target-os=linux \
--cross-prefix=/opt/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--arch=arm \
--cpu=armv7-a \
--enable-runtime-cpudetect \
--sysroot=/opt/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ \
--enable-pic \
--enable-pthreads \
--enable-cross-compile \
--disable-debug \
--disable-ffserver \
--enable-version3 \
--enable-hardcoded-tables \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--enable-gpl \
--enable-yasm \
--disable-doc \
--disable-shared \
--enable-static \
--extra-cflags="-I${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/include $CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="-L${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}/lib $LDFLAGS"
```

Fore details, visit https://sites.google.com/site/greateindiaclub/mobil-apps/android/buildffmpegprebuiltlibraryforanandroid

Comment: This has a LOT of unnecessary options, but most of all you're compiling with an insanely old NDK and 32-bit code. You will need to update this since, 1) GCC of this era doesn't generate great ARM code, and 2) next year Android will require 64-bit code.