# How to build FFMPEG for all architecture of android device?

Tags: android, bash, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to build [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) for android in windows 8.1 using [CYGWIN](https://cygwin.com/)

I am following This [question](http://FFMPEG%20for%20android%20in%20Windows%20not%20successfully%20compile) & [How to compile FFMPEG under Cygwin](http://www.mediaentertainmentinfo.com/2014/01/1-technical-series-how-to-compile-ffmpeg-under-cygwin.html/) . I succsessfully compile but it is not generate **FFMPEG.so** but it generate ffmpeg.exe file

I don't want any prebuild [ffmpeg library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java)  . I want to build it for my requirement.

**I perform this steps In CYGWIN BASE**

1. git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
2. dos2unix configure
3. dos2unix build_ffmpeg.sh
4. make distclean
5. ./configure –enable-static –disable-shared
6. make
7. make install

my **build_ffmpeg.sh** is

> #!/bin/bash
>
> NDK=/cygdrive/e/android/sdk/ndk-bundle
>       PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm
>       TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows
>       CPU=arm
>       PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
>       ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
>
> pushd ffmpeg
>       # Configure
>       ./configure \
>           --target-os=android \
>           --prefix=$PREFIX \
>           --enable-cross-compile \
>           --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
>           --disable-asm \
>           --arch=arm \
>           --cc=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc \
>           --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
>           --disable-stripping \
>           --nm=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-nm \
>           --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
>           --disable-programs \
>           --disable-doc \
>           --enable-protocol=file \
>           --disable-avresample \
>           --enable-gpl \
>           --enable-version3 \
>           --enable-nonfree \
>           --disable-ffplay \
>           --disable-ffserver \
>           --disable-ffmpeg \
>           --disable-ffprobe \
>           --extra-cflags="-fPIC -DANDROID -D__thumb__ -mthumb -Wfatal-errors -Wno-deprecated $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
>           --extra-libs="-lgcc" \
>           --extra-ldflags="-L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog"
>       # Make
>       make clean
>       make -j5
>       make -j5 install
>
> popd

My LOG file is [here](https://gist.github.com/Ubhadiyap/f202db6a729b1287e0ae6d46b858518c#file-config-log)

My question is how to build ffmpeg for all architecture of android device?

Comment: [This link](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) has been credited on the ffmpeg official site. You should find a guide as well as prebuilt binaries.

Comment: @alok is this link contains x64,mips prebuilt library?

Comment: @downvotter if you are successfully compile than give down vote.....

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these links

- https://github.com/hiteshsondhi88/ffmpeg-android
- https://github.com/cine-io/android-ffmpeg-with-rtmp
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/
- http://www.roman10.net/2011/07/17/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

You might find out that you've missed something!

Answer (score 0):

Below post will help you to create ffmpeg for an android with different architecture, use it as on reference for other platforms

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45078822/998483